# Fast Convertion From Adjacency List to Edge List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have an undirected weighted graph implemented with adjacency list which I need to convert to an edge list. The problem is, for each edge `(A, B)`, I have two entries in adjacency list: one indicating an edge to B from A and other from A to B. So, while converting this to edge list, I need to search the whole partially completed edge list to prevent duplicates.

Is there any way I can make that faster/ less complicated? I need to keep the adjacency list because my algorithm of detecting cycles in graph relies on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate you vertices add to your list only edges `(u, v)` such that `u <= v`.

Comment: Okay, that will make searching in the partially completed edge list faster.

Comment: No, you never insert a duplicate that way so you do not have to search at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
//you are given an adjacency matrix adj[]
//you are making an edge list from that matrix 

int n=V;//the no. of vertices
        vector<pair<int,int>>edgeList;
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
          for(int child:adj[i])
          {
              if(child>i)
              edgeList.push_back({i,child});
          }
      }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).